Cutting a rod in n parts
A rod of length 1 unit is cut into n pieces.Find the expected value of the smallest and largest piece.

What method do you use to cut the rod?  Are you picking $(n-1)$ independently and uniformly selected real numbers from $(0,1)$?  Are you selecting one of the current pieces of the rod uniformly at random and then making a cut on that piece uniformly at random before moving on?  Are you always taking the largest piece and making a cut on that?  There is not enough information here in what you have written.

Yes I am picking (−1) independently and uniformly selected real numbers from (0,1)
